# A substructure that is elementary equivalent to its structure, isn't an elementary substructure example mistake?

Tags: model-theory

So we were given this example to show that substructure that is elementary equivalent to its structure, isn't necessarily an elementary substructure.

Just so I'll be clear on the definition: A substructure $M$ of $N$ is an elementary substructure, if for every formula $\phi (v_1, \cdots, v_n)$ and for every $\overline b=(b_1, \cdots, b_n) \in M^n$, $M \vDash \phi( \overline b) \iff N \vDash \phi( \overline b)$.

So the example we were given is $N=(\mathbb N; <)$ and $M=(5,6,7,...;<)$. So there is an isomorphism $f(n)=n+5$, so $N$ and $M$ are elementary equivalent. However, and this is the part I don't get, for $\phi: \exists x: x\lt 5$, indeed $N \vDash \phi$ but $M \not\vDash \phi$. So $M$ isn't an elementary substructure of $N$.

Which is true in general, for $\overline b \in N^n$, but our demand to prove (or refute), is that $\overline b \in M^n$, and there is no such $\overline b$ so that $N \vDash \phi (\overline b)$, or am I missing something here?

Comment: The given formula doesn't have *unbound* variables, i.e. in this case the number $n$ of free arguments for $\phi$ is $n=0$.

However, I doubt we can use the constant $5$ in the formula unless $5$ is a constant of the language...

Comment: I guess he used 5 just to simplify it instead of writing 1+1+1+1+1. Could you explain the first part of what you said?

Comment: The proof is incorrect indeed. The right formula $\psi(y)$ would rather be $\forall x: x  \geq y$. There is an element $b = 5$ of $M^1$ such that $M \vDash \psi(5)$, but $N \vDash \neg \psi(5)$.

Comment: Yes. I agree with nombre, and @Reyo: neither $1$ is given as a constant for the language.

Comment: 5 is not equal to 1+1+1+1+1 because + is not in the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given formula $\phi:=\,\exists x: x<5$ has no unbounded variable, but it uses a *constant* (namely $5$) which is not available in the language, as we only have a binary operation symbol ($<$) and no constant symbols.

As nombre commented, the formula was most probably with a free variable:
$$\phi(y):=\,\exists x:x<y\,.$$

Now we indeed have that $f=n\mapsto n+5$ is an isomorphism between the structures $N$ and $M$, which implies that $N$ and $M$ are elementary equivalent (they validate the same *closed* formulas on the given language).

However, choosing $b=5\in M\subseteq N$ with $\phi$ in the definition of 'elementary substructure', we will have $N\models\phi(5)$ while $M\not\models\phi(5)$.

Comment: Hi, I'm just a little confused about the definitions. We know that every isomorphism is an elementary embedding, isomorphism also means elementary equivalent, and If $M \subset N$ and the containment map is an elementary embedding, then we say that M is an elementary substructure of N. So don't we have a contradiction here? Thanks!

Comment: $M$ is an elementary substructure of $N$ if the *inclusion* ($M\to N:\,x\mapsto x$) itself is an elementary embedding.